# Bash - Error: Syntax error: operand expected (error token is "testdir/.hidd1/")

Tags: linux, bash, syntax-error, hierarchy, operand

I'm working on a task for uni work where the aim is to count all files and directories within a given directory and then all subdirectories as well. We are forbidden from using find, locate, du or any recursive commands (e.g. ls -R).
To solve this I've tried making my own recursive command and have run into the error above, more specificly it is `line 37: testdir/.hidd1/: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ".hidd1/")`
[The Hierarchy I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiO3c.png)
The code for this is as follows:

```
tgtdir=$1
visfiles=0
hidfiles=0
visdir=0
hiddir=0
function searchDirectory {
    curdir=$1

    echo "curdir = $curdir" 
    # Rather than change directory ensure that each recursive call uses the $curdir/NameOfWantedDirectory
    noDir=$(ls -l -A $curdir| grep ^d | wc -l) # Work out the number of directories in the current directory
    echo "noDir = $noDir"

    shopt -s nullglob # Enable nullglob to prevent a null term being added to the array 
    directories=(*/ .*/) # Store all directories and hidden directories into the array 'directories'
    shopt -u nullglob #Turn off nullglob to ensure it doesn't later interfere
    echo "${directories[@]}" # Print out the array directories

    y=0 # Declares a variable to act as a index value
    for i in $( ls -d ${curdir}*/ ${curdir}.*/ ); do # loops through all directories both visible and hidden
        if [[ "${i:(-3)}" = "../" ]]; then
            echo "Found ./"
            continue;
        elif [[ "${i:(-2)}" = "./" ]]; then
            echo "Found ../"
            continue;
        else # When position i is ./ or ../ the loop advances otherwise the value is added to directories and y is incremented before the loop advances
            echo "Adding $i to directories"
            directories[y]="$i"
            let "y++"
        fi
    done # Adds all directories except ./ and ../ to the array directories
    echo "${directories[@]}"
    if [[ "${noDir}" -gt "0" ]]; then
        for i in ${directories[@]}; do
            echo "at position i ${directories[$i]}"
            searchDirectory ${directories[$i]}        #### <--- line 37 - the error line
        done # Loops through subdirectories to reach the bottom of the hierarchy using recursion
    fi

    visfiles=$(ls -l $tgtdir | grep -v ^total | grep -v ^d | wc -l)
    # Calls the ls -l command which puts each file on a new line, then removes the line which states the total and any lines starting with a 'd' which would be a directory with grep -v,
    #finally counts all lines using wc -l
    hiddenfiles=$(expr $(ls -l -a $tgtdir | grep -v ^total | grep -v ^d | wc -l) - $visfiles) 
    # Finds the total number of files including hidden and puts them on a line each (using -l and -a (all)) removes the line stating the total as well as any directoriesand then counts them. 
    #Then stores the number of hidden files by expressing the complete number of files minus the visible files.
    visdir=$(ls -l $tgtdir | grep ^d | wc -l)
    # Counts visible directories by using ls -l then filtering it with grep to find all lines starting with a d indicating a directory. Then counts the lines with wc -l.
    hiddir=$(expr $(ls -l -a $tgtdir | grep ^d | wc -l) - $visdir)
    # Finds hidden directories by expressing total number of directories including hidden - total number of visible directories
    #At minimum this will be 2 as it includes the directories . and ..
    total=$(expr $visfiles + $hiddenfiles + $visdir + $hiddir) # Calculates total number of files and directories including hidden.
}
searchDirectory $tgtdir
echo "Total Files: $visfiles (+$hiddenfiles hidden)"
echo "Directories Found: $visdir (+$hiddir hidden)"
echo "Total files and directories: $total"
exit 0
```

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Run your script through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 37 is `searchDirectory ${directories[$i]}`, as I count.  Yes?

- Replace the for loop with `for i in "${directories[@]}"; do` - add double quotes.  This will keep each element as its own word.
- Replace line 37 with `searchDirectory "$i"`.  The `for` loop gives you each *element* of the array in `i`, not each *index*.  Therefore, you don't need to go into `directories` again - `i` already has the word you need.

Also, I note that the `echo`s on lines 22 and 25 are swapped :) .

Comment: Cheers, this has helped alot

Comment: Thank you, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Would you please upvote (upward triangle) or accept (checkmark) this answer so others will know it was useful?  Also see the tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour for more info and to get a badge :) .